# image in a tag does not displaying

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small gamer web page using HTML,CSS and JS. I wanted to make the link icons from the pictures of the games but when I putted the images into a element, web browser didn't display them.
[This is the situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dheaE.png)

Here are the codes:

```
<div class="nav">
        <nav>
        <a href=""><img src="Lol.svg" alt="League Of Legends Icon"> League Of Legends</a>
        <a href=""><img src="Diablo3.svg" alt="Diablo 3 Icon"> Diablo III</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? Are those images in the same location as that HTML file? Are they successfully located, and retrieved from, the server?

Comment: are the images in the same directory as the file?

Comment: All the HTML codes, CSS codes and svg files are in same location. There are no any errors in my browser console. My browser see them but not displaying them. ( When I source svg link in the console, I can see the link and image )

Comment: Check the network tab, not the console. There you can see which files the browser is loading. If it says something like `404` the image can't be found. Or maybe it just renderst the image at 0x0 size, try setting a min-width / min-height to the images. But we can only guess at this point.

Comment: There is no error in network tab either. There is only one problem in console that ''Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelected')
    at popup.js:7'' but it is not related with image situation I think.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that you have pictures in the same folder. If it's in folder "Pictures" in folder where you have this .html file then you need to write src="Pictures/Lol.svg" and so on. If it's from outside folder then you can go back from folder, where this .html file is, by writing src="../Lol.svg" (this is one folder back ../../Lol.svg would be 2 folders back)

Comment: They are all in the same folder. (Codes and images)

Comment: Can you show me picture of the folder?